# Android application crash on getPackageManager

Tags: android

In my android application I need to get the version of the application programatically. But whenever I try with this code it crashes at this line. Is there anything that I am missing

```
PackageInfo pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    this.getPackageName(), 0);
```

I tried getting it from PackageManager and PackageInfo. In both the cases the application crashes and launches ViewRoot.handleMessage and I get a message "Source Not found"

Comment: have you write this code in any activity ?

Comment: Yes I have added it in a function.

Comment: have you tried my code ?

Comment: Go into Logcat and post the logs here; the code looks basically correct so it's hard to determine what's going wrong without seeing crash logs.

Comment: Thank You Daniel.. Will check the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below function.

```
public int getVersion(Context context) 
{
        try 
        {
            PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("here.thenameofyour.package", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            return pInfo.versionCode;
        } 
        catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chirag Raval. This helped me. Really good piece of code.